# Python renaming file with regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I want to rename files with one source pattern (for example IMG_20190401_235959.jpg) to a destination pattern (for example 2019-04-01_23_59_59.jpg)

I'm trying to do that in python but i can't find out how to use a regex to build the new filename :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, glob, sys, re    
os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
for filename in glob.glob("IMG_*.jpg"):
    newfilename = re.sub(?????
    try:
       os.rename(filename,newfilename)
    except OSError,e:
       print e
```

Comment: Do you actually need a regex? I'm sure most users could provide you with a good non-regex solution very quickly.

Comment: If all of the files have the exact same length, why use RegEx? A solution off the top of my head would be to `.split('')` the filename, add the characters you need, and rejoin.

Comment: Why do you want to shift it 3 days forward? (or is it a mistake? 20190401 -> 2019-04-04)

Comment: You can start by splitting the file-name (without ext) by underscore, then you'll have three parts, the first you can discard and parse the other two parts. I don't see any advantage for regex here, you can parse these fields either as date/time or as strings.

Comment: @alfasin yes it is a mistake.

Comment: yes i want a regex because the source and destination pattern can be different than those i provided. I think in this case a regex is more suitable, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to precompile the RegEx before using it. You can proceed that way:

```py
import re

sub_name = re.compile(r"IMG_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", flags=re.I).sub
```

Here, *sub_name* is a function that you can use later in you `for` loop to replace the name of each image.

Note: Ignoring the case (upper/lower-case) can be useful under Windows, but you also need to adapt the call to `glob.glob`.

Below is a solution which use `glob.glob` but you can also use `os.walk` to browse a directory, searching all images…

```py
# coding: utf-8
import glob
import os
import re
import sys

sub_name = re.compile(r"IMG_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", flags=re.I).sub

work_dir = sys.argv[1]

for old_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "IMG_*.jpg")):
    dirname, old_name = os.path.split(old_path)
    new_name = sub_name("\\1-\\2-\\3_\\4_\\5_\\6", old_name)
    new_path = os.path.join(dirname, new_name)
    try:
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
    except OSError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

I noticed that you use the `print` statement, and the Python 2.6 syntax for exception. It is preferable to use the new syntax.
If you use Python 2.7, you can add the directive:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
```

Put it at the top of your imports…

Answer (score 6):

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^IMG_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.jpeg$')

oldStr = 'IMG_20190401_235959.jpeg';

match = regex.match(oldStr)

newStr = '{}-{}-{}_{}_{}.jpg'.format(*match.groups())

print(newStr) # 2019-04-01_23_59.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` to grab the necessary groups from the file path, and the rejoin:

```
import re
def new_path(s):
  _, a, b, f_type = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', s)
  new_b = '_'.join(b[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(b), 2))
  return f'{a[:4]}-{a[4:6]}-{a[6:]}_{new_b}.{f_type}'

print(new_path('IMG_20190401_235959.jpg'))
```

Output:

```
'2019-04-01_23_59_59.jpg'
```

Then:

```
import os, glob, sys, re    
os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
for filename in glob.glob("IMG_*.jpg"):
  try:
    os.rename(filename, new_path(filename))
  except OSError,e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if regex is the best option here. You can split it up and use basic string operations pretty easily:

```
original = 'IMG_20190401_235959.jpg'
ol = original.split('_')
date = f'{ol[1][:4]}-{ol[1][4:6]}-{ol[1][6:8]}'
time = f'{ol[2][:2]}_{ol[2][2:4]}_{ol[2][4:6]}'
new = f'{date}_{time}.jpg'
print(new)
```

Comment: I like this approach.  simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me, however it only uses regex to remove the `IMG_` in the filename, so you can also just drop the regex completely.

```
newfilename = re.sub('IMG_', '', filename)
newfilename = newfilename[0:4] + '-' + newfilename[4:6] + '-' + newfilename[6:11] + '_' + newfilename[11:13] + '_' + newfilename[13:]
```

Comment: Instead of using RegEx at all, why not just do `newfilename = newfilename[4:]` instead of the `re.sub`?

Comment: Ya, that's what I mean with the comment "...so you can also just drop the regex completely."

Answer (score 0):

If your input is consistent, this should work:

```
import re
pattern = r"IMG_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})"
test_str = "IMG_20190401_235959.jpg"
subst = "\\1-\\2-\\3_\\4_\\5_\\6"
result = re.sub(pattern, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)

# 2019-04-01_23_59_59.jpg
```